# How do I add a .framework file to my cmake file

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clion

I downloaded the SDL2 library to use in my C++ project. I'm on OSX. I moved the SDL2.framework into my /Library/Frameworks directory.

I have no idea how to refer to this file in my cmake file in my c++ project. Wonder if someone could shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

As any other library:

```
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
```

Then use `${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR}` and `${SDL2_LIBRARY}` variables where needed (for example in places like `target_include_directories()`, `target_link_libraries()` or `set_target_properties()`).

If it complains about missing `*.cmake` script, then get somewhere on the Internet a `FindSDL2.cmake` file. Put it into `modules/` directory in your project, and add that to the main `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/modules/")
```